# How do I write test cases for a BigQuery SQL query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am trying to write BigQuery related code inside PySpark job. I want to write tests for BigQuery related code? Can I do this?

I have tried to look at BigQuery official documenation page. But I am unable to find it.

Answer (score -1):

It's a very large question and if you want to test `Bigquery` `SQL` queries, it corresponds to integration tests.

You can use a `Cloud function`, `Cloud run` job in `serverless` mode with `Bigquery` `Python` client to test your `UDF` or `SQL` queries.

You can also use a pipeline orchestrator like `Cloud workflow` in serverless mode to execute your queries.

In this example, I am showing an example with `Cloud Workflow`.

In my team, we chose to execute our `Bigquery` integration tests with a real infrastructure and not with emulators.

We created a testing framework based on `Terraform` :

- Setup and creation of `short-lived` infra in a dedicated `Terraform` unique `workspace` for the current test (creation of `datasets` and `tables` needed to test queries)
- Launch a `DAG` with `Cloud Workflow` to execute your queries
- The `DAG` compare the result (actual) to given expected list
- Teardown and destroying the `short-lived` infra on the `workspace` for the current tests

My answer corresponds to examples for my experiences and feedbacks, but there are many ways to apply integrations tests on `Bigquery` and `GCP` and you have to think of the best way in your case.